# Error a hacer deploy en vercel de una web app con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Buenas hacer varios dias estoy intentando hacer deploy de una web app en vercel y me esta tirando este error que no se de que puede ser.

[image: error]

Por lo que veo viene de redux pero, si huiera un error supongo que la app no funcionaria y funciona a la perfeccion. Probe de desinstalar redux e instalarlo de nuevo, tambien uso redux toolkit pero creo que seria solo de redux por lo que dice el mensaje de error

dejo el link de mi repo: https://github.com/guidomora/JournalApp.git

Comment: Hola guido, para poder ayudarte necesitamos ver tu código, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y lo agregues como texto, así también evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Guido me clone tu git y para solucionar debes de instalar redux pero con el parámetro --save de la siguiente forma

```
npm install react-redux --save
```

Te dejo el git clonado https://github.com/JkDevArg/journey-t1

y el deploy https://journey-t1-jkdevarg.vercel.app/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esper haberte ayudado

Comment: muchas gracias!!! Pregunta: que cambia con agregarle el  "--save"? pq yo habia hecho npm install react reduc pero sin es  "--save"

Comment: El parámetro "--save" es para guardar el modulo  instalado en el package.json y así no tener problemas en el futuro.

Comment: Entonces para futuras instalaciones me conviene agregarle a todas ese parámetro o solo para módulos especificos?